# UIView animation in UITableViewCell works only once

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview

Here's a strange fact :

I have a custom UITableViewCell in which I have an animation (an image moves).

It works fine on the creation of the cell.

But once I scroll to hide the cell and then go back on it, the animation has stopped. That, I can understand. But I'm calling my animation method in my viewWillAppear too. And the wired part is that the method is called, I've put a breakpoint in it, nothing is desallocated...

My UITableViewCell is kept strongly (there's a music player in it, the music continues to play). I really don't get it.

Here's my code :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) DWPlayerCellVC *playerView;


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"player"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"player"];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        NSArray *viewsToRemove = [cell.contentView subviews];
        for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }

        if(!self.playerView){
            self.playerView = [[DWPlayerCellVC alloc] init];
        }

        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.playerView.view];

        self.playerView.model = self.model[indexPath.row];


        return cell;
```

DWPlayerCellVC :

```
@implementation DWPlayerCellVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self zoomIn];
}

- (void)setModel:(id)model
{
    _model = model;
     // ...
    [self zoomIn];

}

- (void)zoomIn
{
    UIViewAnimationOptions options =
    UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState |
    UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut |
    UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
    UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse;

    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:10.f
     delay:0.f
     options:options
     animations:^{
         CGFloat scale = 1.4f;
         self.imageCoverView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
     } completion:NULL];
}
```

If you have any ideas...

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is because `zoomIn` will only ever be called by `setModel`. This is because `UITabelViewCells` are not expected to managed displaying `UIViewControllers` so `viewWillAppear:` will never be called.

There are two options that I can think of.

The first would be to set up your root view controller to be a containment view controller and add the `DWPlayerCellVC` as a `childViewController`. This option does involve some work to get it all running, I suggect reading [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) to see whets required to get it working.

The second (and the one I would use) would be to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass that handles running the animation. Then you can just implement the method `prepareForReuse` to restart the animation. That method is automatically called on a cell when you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: I've put a breakpoint in viewWillAppear: and in zoomIn and the 2 methods are called. That's the strange part ! :/

Answer (score 0):

Your UITableViewCell will remember it's state from before. When it's put into the queue (when it scrolls out of view), it doesn't revert back to a pristine state. When you call your ZoomIn method, I think what's happening is that it's zooming in again, but you can't tell because it's *already zoomed in*.

Try - before you zoom in, ensure that it's zoomed out. So in ViewWillAppear, to a quick "Reset" of the Cell, and then call zoomIn, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: The thing is that it's an infinite animation (UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
    UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse) so it's suppose to zoom in and out forever. And it's what it does the first time...